# Elasticsearch highlight: how to get entire text of the field in Java client

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to Elasticsearch. I am hoping to get highlighted field in Java client. If I run the following query in Windows prompt:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered" : {
            "query" : {
                "term" : {
                    "title" : "western"
                }
            },
            "filter" : {
                "term" : { "year" : 1961 }
            }
        }
    },
    "highlight" : {
        fields" : {
            "title" : {}
            }
        }
}
```

I get nice highlighted text as follows:

```
{
      "_index" : "book",
      "_type" : "history",
      "_id" : "1",
      "_score" : 0.095891505,
      "_source":{ "title": "All Quiet on the Western great Front", "year": 1961}
      "highlight" : {
        "title" : [ "All Quiet on the <em>Western</em> great Front dead" ]
      }
}
```

The highlight

```
  "highlight" : {
    "title" : [ "All Quiet on the <em>Western</em> great Front dead" ]
  }
```

can be easily converted into a Java Map object, and the "title" property contains the entire text of the matched field, which is really what I want.

However, in Java client, I get highlighted fragments, which puts different segments of highlighted text of the same field into an array of text.

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the Java API the default number of fragments that are returned is 5. So if you only want one fragment to be returned you need to set that.

```
client.prepareSearch("book")
 .setTypes("history")
 .addHighlightedField("title")
 .setQuery(query)
 .setHighlighterFragmentSize(2000)
 .setHighlighterNumOfFragments(1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You may also set the number of fragments to 0 which will display the entire field with highlighting tags. This will also ignore fragment_size.

```
.setHighlighterNumOfFragments(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I found and I am not sure whether it is the right or best solution. In Java client, use setHighlighterFragmentSize method:

```
SearchResponse sr = client.prepareSearch("book")
                .setTypes("history")
                .addHighlightedField("title")
                .setQuery(query)
                .setHighlighterFragmentSize(2000) //set it larger than the size of the field so that the only one fragment is returned and it contains the entire text of the field.
```

I really want to hear what experts out there say and choose their reply as the answer.

Regards.